# "Automatically adjust brightness" nowhere to be seen

Tags: display, settings, cinema-display

I have a situation where I'm using an app that calibrates my monitors.  I have several monitors attached and when I go into `System Preferences` -> `Displays`, I unfortunately don't see any options on any of my monitors to toggle an `Automatically adjust brightness` setting as per the instructions:

[image: SuperCal]

My displays consist of:

- 1x 30" Apple Cinema HD Display ([Display Pane](https://cl.ly/3x290w0h1k2y),
  [Options Pane](https://cl.ly/2B3v2m0W1K10))
- 1x Dell U2711 ([Display Panel](https://cl.ly/0t1N3K3r1I0c))
- 1x Acer G257HU ([Display Panel](https://cl.ly/210m1F0a2J1A))
- 2x Sceptre E248W-1920R ([Display Panel](https://cl.ly/3V0E1N2x1l3w))

I'm running MacOS 10.12.5.

*Any ideas on how to disable such a setting that is no where to be seen?*

Comment: Operating system version?

Comment: @Catija macOS 10.12.5.

Comment: Have you tried to lock settings for Cinema Display and run again SuperCal?

Comment: Something along those lines crossed my mind, but I don't see a way to "lock" the settings for the Cinema Display.  I did "Disable brightness buttons", but are there other options I'm missing @AndreyKuznetsov?

Comment: https://cl.ly/2B3v2m0W1K10 Lock symbol :-)

Comment: @AndreyKuznetsov no, that is just a settings lock for making changes. That's been toggled multiple times and does not affect anything: https://cl.ly/1Z0i1b2K1J3S